# JavaScript Copy Array By Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, copy

I have created an array and received another from a php file.
The data is fine but when i try to copy one array to another, it seems like when i change arr1 then arr2 is also changed.

It is being copied "by reference" and not "by value" as i need

I also tried slice() butit doesn't work, The variable does not being copied at all, not even "by reference" in that way.

```
// arr1[0] = "Hey";//this array is coming from another file and the data is fine
var arr2 = [];

arr2[0] = arr1[0];
arr2[0] += "1"; // right now arr1 and arr2 both has "Hey1" in them.
```

Any ideas?
Thank You

Comment: Are you quite sure that *both* those arrays have "Hey1" in them?

Comment: It doesn't do that for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/sxochn11/

Comment: This would happen if you did `arr2 = arr1`, not the code you showed.

Comment: I think your example doesn't reflect your actual program enough.  Are you, by chance, substituting objects in your real program with strings here?  Because what you are showing is not how Javascript works: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hagcx71a/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is an object in Javascript. As you might know objects are copied by reference. You could take a look here: [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a deep, rather than a shallow, copy of an array of strings like this:

```
var arr2 = [], i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arr2[i] = String(arr1[i]);
}
```

EDITED: oops, swapped deep and shallow.

Comment: He's not copying the array anywhere.